Why doesn't latent heat change the temperature?
Seems like there is this new type of heat in town.
Temperature is just the average kinetic energy; heat is basically movement of particles, so basically kinetic energy, so temperature is the measure of heat?
My teacher told me that the heat energy is converted to kinetic energy, so there is no change in temperature. But heat energy is basically kinetic energy, and temperature is the measure of kinetic energy. Maybe my understanding of latent heat isn't crisp, if so please explain it to me.


heat is basically movement of particles or HEAT IS BASICALLY KINETIC ENERGY That is a common use of the word heat, but it is the more colloquial, misleading use. The proper physics (thermodynamic) meaning of the word "heat" is not "movement of particles", but amount of energy transferred due to close contact (proximity of bodies), not associated with any visible kind of work. Thus heat is energy transferred in a particular way, not "energy sitting in some place".


In what sense is latent heat new?

Latent heat does "change the temperature".  When ice melts, it changes the temperature of its surroundings.

@pm-2ring cause i was in middle school and i just so happened to learn about it


Temperature is just the average kinetic energy, heat is basically
movement of particles, so basically kinetic energy, so temperature is
the measure of heat?

Heat is not basically the movement of particles. Heat is the transfer of energy between objects solely due to temperature difference. It is a mechanism for transferring energy from one object to another.
By transferring energy from object A to object B, heat may result in slowing down the motion of the particles (molecules) in object A  while speeding up the motion of the particles (molecules) in object B. In other words it may transfer kinetic energy (translational, rotational, and/or vibrational kinetic energy) from object A to B.  But heat is not the kinetic energy itself. So your teacher is incorrect.  These transfers of kinetic energy may lower the temperature of A and increase the temperature of B based on the mass and the specific heat properties of the objects.
I said “may transfer kinetic energy”, because if heat is causing a phase change in object A and/or B (e.g., solid to liquid or liquid to solid) the energy transfer causes the molecules to separate or come closer together changing the molecular potential energy of the object without changing kinetic energy, and thus without changing the temperature of the object(s) undergoing phase change. This is the heat called latent heat.
The changes in molecular kinetic and molecular potential energy together comprise changes in what is properly called the internal energy of the the objects.
If you can get a copy, I recommend you read the paper The Use and Misuse of the Word "Heat" in Physics Teaching by noted thermodynamics teacher Mark Zemansky.

Why does the heat energy deal with potential energy instead of kinetic
energy during a phase change? Why can't it just increase/decrease the
kinetic energy instead of increasing/decreasing the potential energy?

During a phase change it is always observed that the temperature does not change. That means there is no increase or decrease in the translational kinetic energy of the molecules when heat, referred to as latent heat, is supplied to or extracted from the substance. Instead, latent heat either breaks or establishes bonds between the molecules of the substance during phase change, increasing or decreasing the molecular potential energy of the substance.
Hope this helps.

Why does the heat energy deal with potential energy instead of kinetic energy during a phase change?
Why can't it just increase/decrease the kinetic energy instead of increasing/decreasing the potential energy?

E@PhineSine I will update my answer to respond to your follow up question

@PhineSine See update to my answer.

Yeah but why did the universe just ditch kinetic energy during a phase change

@PhineSine Kinetic energy isn't "ditched" during a phase change. It is converted to potential energy.

yeah but why is that it gets converted during a phase change?

@PhineSine. Where else does the energy come from to break the bonds and cause a  solid to change into a liquid?

turns out i forgot that energy is conserved. TYSM


But heat energy is basically kinetic energy

Thermal energy is not basically kinetic energy. Thermal energy includes molecular level translational and rotational modes, which are purely kinetic, but it also includes vibrational, torsional, and electronic modes which include potential energy as well. The average thermal energy is the same in all of these modes at thermal equilibrium. Temperature is proportional to the average energy per mode, regardless of whether the energy in a mode is kinetic, potential, or a mix.
The idea that thermal energy is kinetic energy stems from studying ideal gasses, where there are no other internal modes. But not all materials are ideal gasses, particularly not when a system is undergoing a phase change. Do not over-generalize what you learned from ideal gasses.
In latent heat, what is happening is that more of these internal modes are being recruited. As additional thermal energy is added it is not going into increasing the average energy in each mode, but it is instead going into increasing the number of modes that contain the same average energy. For example, in melting, there are vibrational modes in the solid and in the liquid there are also translational modes. As latent heat is added more of the molecules excite the translational modes, corresponding to the change from solid to liquid at a fixed temperature.

In latent heat, what is happening is that more of these internal modes are being recruited. – That claim fails if you look at the evaporation of a liquid. Here you are losing the vibrational modes from molecule interactions. As a result the specific heat capacity just above the boiling point is usually (if not always) lower than below. Also, you would have a latent heat when thawing degrees of freedom, e.g., when internal vibrational modes become available at a few thousand kelvins – which is not the case.

Being historically correct, temperature is just what was measured via the length of a column of mercury because, we humans observed that the hotter the objects get, the greater the mercury rises; hence it is called the measure of the hotness or coldness. Now Kelvin gave his absolute scale of measurement, which has its history too, but the conversion between Celsius and Kelvin is easy. We cannot say temperature is the average kinetic energy of molecule but it is definitely closely associated to the average kinetic energy of each molecule in a gas.
If we are talking about an ideal gas, the equation $E=\frac{3}{2} \cdot KT$ captures the direct relation of temperature and the average kinetic energy of the molecule. The difference in units shows that indeed temperature is not average kinetic energy itself, but changes in temperature indicate changes in average kinetic energy.
Keeping this in mind, heat is not temperature either; it is simply energy in a transfer from one thermodynamic system to another.
Now this acquired energy can be stored in different forms, like kinetic energy of molecules, potential energy of weak interactions etc.
When a gas rises in temperature, vibrational and rotational and other kinds of kinetic energy are increased, which you correctly identified to be changes of average kinetic energy of the molecules. This is only for an ideal gas which assumes amongst others that there are no intermolecular interaction between the molecules.
As far as real gases are concerned, this answer by Poutnik explains where the latent heat goes when temperature is not increasing, but phases are changing:

The majority of latent heat, both for melting and evaporation, is due the release of intermolecular bonding. It is either van der Waals-like forces for non-polar molecules, or dipole-dipole bonding, donor–acceptor electron pair bonding, or hydrogen bonds of highly polar molecules. For example, it is estimated that water – if there were no hydrogen bonds – would melt at −160 °C and boil at −120 °C.

